# Can the sendinput API simulate a keyboard key being held down during some time?

Tags: windows, keyboard, key, simulate, sendinput

My app will need to simulate a key being held down during some time. I don't know how many time. Can I use the sendinput API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) can trigger events with [`INPUT` structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646270(VS.85).aspx) including [`KEYBDINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271(VS.85).aspx).  A `KEYBDINPUT` can specify key up and key down events using virtual keys or scan codes.  So you want to use `SendInput` twice: send a key down event at the beginning, and a key up event at the end.

Comment: You will only receive that key press once. For example: `x` rather than `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.